# How to hide createMaterialTopTabNavigator from top in React-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want createMaterialTopTabNavigator should be hidden how to do that

```
const TopTabNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  one:LogedInChatBot,
  two:ScreenTwo,
  three:ScreenThree
},{
  tabBarOptions:{

  }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
  tabBarOptions: {
    style: {
      display: 'none'
    }
  }
```

Source : https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5428#issuecomment-517112669-permalink

Hopefully they will add a `tabBarVisible` prop as done in the `createBottomTabNavigator`